# How to delete website and stores in magneto2.4.6

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4, configuration

Post upgradation of magento 2.4.6 delete option is not available to delete the website and stores in magento admin.

Does anyone know how to delete website and stores through admin in magento2.4.6?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the website and store from here.

1. Open `Magento Admin.`
2. Go To `Stores -> All Stores.`
3. Where you see all current `websites and stores` list into the grid.
4. Now click on the website name, if you want to delete website.
   In Edit section, you found the options of `"Delete Website"`